# Selenium: Reload page when ValueError: No tables found

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium-webdriver

I really need a solution

How to trigger selenium to try and reload the url once before moving on to the next url?

Code:

```
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    from selenium import webdriver
    from tabulate import tabulate
    from datetime import datetime
    import time
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    class GameData:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.date = []
            self.time = []
            self.game = []
            self.score = []
            self.home_odds = []
            self.draw_odds = []
            self.away_odds = []
            self.country = []
            self.league = []
    
    
    def parse_data(url):
        browser.get(url)
        df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
        html = browser.page_source
        soup = bs(html, "lxml")
        cont = soup.find('div', {'id': 'wrap'})
        content = cont.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
        content = content.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'}, {'id': 'tournamentTable'})
        main = content.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
        if main is None:
            return None
        count = main.findAll('a')
        country = count[1].text
        league = count[2].text
        game_data = GameData()
        game_date = None
        for row in df.itertuples():
            if not isinstance(row[1], str):
                continue
            elif ':' not in row[1]:
                game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]
                continue
            game_data.date.append(game_date)
            game_data.time.append(row[1])
            game_data.game.append(row[2])
            game_data.score.append(row[3])
            game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
            game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
            game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])
            game_data.country.append(country)
            game_data.league.append(league)
        return game_data
    
    
    urls = {
    "https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/kazakhstan/premier-league-2018/results/#/page/8/"
}
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        results = None
    
        for url in urls:
            game_data = parse_data(url)
            if game_data is None:
                continue
            result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
            if results is None:
                results = result
            else:
                results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)
```

Sometimes when the page does not load correctly (for some reason), it returns an error:

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_30.py", line 1935, in <module>
    game_data = parse_data(url)
  File "C:/Users/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_30.py", line 37, in parse_data
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
....
  File "C:\Users\Documents\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 543, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
```

How to trigger selenium to try and reload the url once before moving on to the next url in the list when such an error occurs?

Thanks

Comment: On which line is the error thrown? Is it an exception or ? Add some details to your question.

Comment: @JeffC added reproduceable code. Thanks